# How do I get access to the running test information (screenshot pattern params)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I would like to store some information using the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` hooks in a fixture like:
   - tracking the REST API calls
   - browser console information
and would like to store this information next to the screenshots.

Is there a way to get access to the screenshot params and current path and also know if a test had an assert during it's run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get access to the screenshot params and current path

It is not possible to access this information in beforeEach/afterEach. TestCafe provides an API to obtain screenshot params for [reports](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/reporter-methods.html#screenshots-object) only.

> if a test had an assert during it's run

If a test is successful, there is no any logged information. If a test fails, information about errors will be written to reports.

Comment: Ok so writing a reporter seems like the way to go.  Thanks!